# Excel 2016 no longer has the menu when filling by dragging the handle. Can I get it back?

Tags: microsoft-excel, feature-regression

It seems that one of the recent updates to O365, has changed the behavior of Excel in a way I don't like (unsurprising, as most Microsoft updates change things in a way I don't like).

Excel used to give you options when drag-copying by the black box at the bottom right of a cell.  [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/790766) has a picture with an example:

[image]

Recently, Excel stopped doing this, and now I see a different menu.  This new menu does not have the same options, nor do I find any value in teh options it does offer.  I'm not sure what it's called (It says Formatting, Charts, Totals, Tables, Sparklines), but you can see it in this first relevant picture from [DuckDuckGO](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=excel%202016%20formatting%20charts%20totals%20tables%20sparklines&t=ffsb&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images&iai=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic1.businessinsider.com%2Fimage%2F5488b3d3ecad044b0d8b4567-1200%2Fexcel-charts-graphs-pivot-tables-made-easy.jpg), towards the bottom:

[image]

I would like the old menu back, as I used it quite heavily.  Can I switch it back?  If so, how do I do that?  Regardless, what are these features called, so I can describe them properly?

Answer (score 1):

The seemingly new feature is called "Quick Analysis".  For some reason, I had that enabled.

There is an option in `Options -> General` to "Show Quick Analysis options on selection".  Unchecking that box got me back to what I wanted.